# Define search path for shared libraries on app execution

Tags: chroot, x-server

#### Final goal:

I'm searching for a way to develop a GUI application under an independent environment without using VirtualBox/VM Ware/Docker.

#### What I did:

I created a chroot environment that I can develop my application in. I can edit and compile the code.

#### Problem:

Running a GUI app inside a chroot is difficult because I need to install and configure an X-Server... and/or connect it to my host X-Server (as far as I understood)

**The idea:**
I could run the application outside of chroot simply on my host machine.

**Problem:**

Of course all dependencies for the executed app are missing because they are not under `/`, but instead under `/home/user/mychroot/`.

#### Question:

Is it possible to run the app while telling it, that all shared items/object (like libraries,...) are in a different path?

Any other approach to the main problem is welcome.

#### Why no docker/vm?

Both are quite slow - especially when run on an external HDD. I used to develop within a vm, but about 50% of the time I'm just trying to solve problems for the vm itself. E.g.: VM froze: restart (takes about 5 tries, each try 10 minutes); VM needs an update: busy for the next 1 - 3 hours; ... .

Answer (score 1):

After trying for a while I resorted of using the "general approach":

- Within chroot (guest):

  - Type `export DISPLAY=:0.0`
- On host:

  - Write in terminal: `xhost +` ("allow x-server connection from chroot")

After using type `xhost -` on host.

[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot#Accessing_graphical_applications_inside_the_chroot)

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/mychroot/usr/lib /home/user/mychroot/yourapp
```

Comment: That "didn't work". I guess it might work, if there are only dependecies in the lib directory. However, many apps use /usr, ... as well (The question was too "library"-focussed; Changed it). I posted my solution.